# YouTube intent, error 400

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I found that I can start a YouTube video in stock YouTube player this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:U79wVTdnMpw")); 
startActivity(i);
```

But it doesn't work. The YouTube player is started, but I get an error:

> There was a problem with the network [400]

I have updated the YouTube app but nothing changes.

I am using Android ICS 4.0.1.

Comment: accept the which one answer helps you.. all new users may be confused

Comment: 3 years later, I don't think @POMATu will ever accept an answer :(

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found the answer on this [Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/FQoBYsObhBQ/7TVtMuGxyk8J) which helped to solve my problem - which was exactly the problem you're experiencing :)

SOLUTION: Give ONLY the **YouTube ID** and not the entire YouTube URL to the `loadVideo()` function.

Answer (score 6):

On loadvideo don't put:

```
loadvideo(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQy4I5y1ldg12)
```

just put

```
loadvideo(gQy4I5y1ldg12);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a common problem with the youtube app, also described [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/21R-bX-bqpY) and [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/FQoBYsObhBQ).
The only answer I found is to log out of the youtube app and then log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Click the **share** button below the youtube video -> It will show the link -> Use this link.

**Note: Not use the url of youtube**

***Screenshot for sample link sharing:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Youtube 400 network error:
Turn off and on
Clear data and cache

Settings
applications
manage applications
clear data and cache

You will need to log in each time.
Unfortunately I still can not post but can share comment on g+

Answer (score 0):

Please chaeck video id is proper parse in json and it perfectly going with intent