# youtube video 400 network when try to play video

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am try to play video using youtube video API

When I put static ID means declare ID in file at that time code is working.

But when I try to fetch ID from getIntent() I also got ID but video not play.

I got There was problem with network.

Below is my code. Its working in this condition.

```
public String VIDEO = "QqnBjKnwCwE";

youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, Videosshow.this);

@Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        player.loadVideo(String.valueOf( VIDEO));
    }
```

Now When I used

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

        VIDEO=data.getString("videourl");
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, Videosshow.this);
```

not working I got 400 Network problem error

Comment: try this answer.. I am also face same problem fixed by this idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/37747713/3879847

Answer (score 1):

Check your id .I think there is space in id or youtube url either start or end .I have similar problem and solved by this .You should also try .It may be help for if you have setup all properly .

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the id I was sending was incorrect, it had an extra = (say =hdeFZ6nt9tc)which was not to be sent. The problem occurred as I was extracting it from the youtube's actual URL(say https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdeFZ6nt9tc). I hope even you too might have been sending the wrong id.
**Double check it again even if you are pretty sure.**
What I think is youtube must send a 404(which generally refers to "Page Not Found" on the web) for such requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had same the problem but retrieving video id from url solved my problem.

```
String video_id=jsonObject.getString("id");
```

Thank You ritesh.